# Parse an string output in batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a Kaspersky output from an scan by calling avp.com in a batch program. I have this output in a variable named RES, the content of this variable is:

[image]

I need to parse this string to get the **Total detected** value, in the above example is **0**. I have tried with the **for** statement in batch, but not getting the result as expected.

Note:Edited with the anwser of @mbroshi

```
set KAVDir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10 for Windows\avp.com"
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%i in ('%KAVDir% /i0 %1 ^| FINDSTR "Total detected"') 
do 
( 
SET RES=%%i 
ECHO %RES% 
)
```

The text of the output of an execution of the avp.com program is:

```
2014-02-26 15:01:58 Scan_Objects$0697         starting   1%         
; --- Settings ---
; Action on detect:     Ask user
; Scan objects:         All objects
; Use iChecker:         Yes
; Use iSwift:           Yes
; Try disinfect:        Yes
; Try delete:           Yes
; Try delete container: No
; Exclude by mask:      No
; Include by mask:      No
; Objects to scan:      
;   "D:\Codigo\Git_Segmail\mail_filters\segmail20\server\service_node_helpers\antivirusscripts\eicar.com.txt"   Enable=Yes  Recursive=No
; ------------------
2014-02-26 15:01:58 D:\Codigo\Git_Segmail\mail_filters\segmail20\server\service_node_helpers\antivirusscripts\eicar.com.txt:Zone.Identifier ok
Progress 50%...
2014-02-26 15:01:58 D:\Codigo\Git_Segmail\mail_filters\segmail20\server\service_node_helpers\antivirusscripts\eicar.com.txt detected    EICAR-Test-File
Progress 50%...
2014-02-26 15:01:58 Scan_Objects$0697         running    50%        
2014-02-26 15:02:00 D:\Codigo\Git_Segmail\mail_filters\segmail20\server\service_node_helpers\antivirusscripts\eicar.com.txt was deleted
2014-02-26 15:02:00 Scan_Objects$0697         completed             
;  --- Statistics ---
;  Current time:    2014-02-26 15:02:00
; Time Start:           2014-02-26 15:01:58
; Time Finish:          2014-02-26 15:02:00
; Completion:           100%
; Processed objects:    2
; Total detected:       1
; Detected exact:       1
; Suspicions:           0
; Treats detected:      1
; Untreated:            0
; Disinfected:          0
; Quarantined:          0
; Deleted:              1
; Skipped:              0
; Archived:             0
; Packed:               0
; Password protected:   0
; Corrupted:            0
; Errors:               0
; Last object:          
;  ------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set KAVDir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10 for Windows\avp.com"
FOR /f "eol=#tokens=2delims=:" %%a IN ('%KAVDir% /i0 %1 ^|find "Total detected"') DO SET /a totdet=%%a
ECHO Total detected is %totdet%
GOTO :EOF
```

Note that `findstr "Total detected"` will find any lines containing "Total" **or** "detected", hence the use of `FIND` (could also have been done with `findstr /c:"Total detected"`

Comment: Yep--forgot about that `/c`.  More importantly, I forgot the default eol is `;`!

Comment: Thanks both for the reply, this one in particular help me solve the problem, then I knew what was the problem with the other one. Thanks @mbroshi and @Magoo!

Comment: Note that to this example works fine it is needed to add the **call** statement before %KAVDir%.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe to `FINDSTR` to get the line you need:

```
set KAVDir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10 for Windows\avp.com"
for /f "eol=# tokens=4 delims= " %%i in (
    '%KAVDir% /i0 %1 ^| FINDSTR /C:"Total detected"'
) do (
    set RES=%%i
)
```

**Edit**: As pointed out by Magoo, I needed to add a `/C` to search for the exact string "Total detected" and added a different `eol` in the `for` loop, as by default it will skip lines beginning with a `;`.

Comment: Thanks por the reply @mbroshi, I don't know why but the RES value that is setted is an empty string. Should I try something else? Thanks

Comment: @yosoy Can you post the actual text of the line to your question?  I'm setting the delimiter to space and grabbing the third token in the above script.  E.g., perhaps there are tabs in `%KAVdir%` variable.

Comment: I have edited the question putting the exact text I have in the .bat file. I added the call statement, but still with no good results. I also put the output of the call statement by calling this one and saving the output to a file.